# why I get mv permission denied error right after react-scripts build?

Tags: reactjs, build, mv, react-scripts

I modified build:dev command as follows.

```
"build:dev": "cp .env.dev ./.env && react-scripts build && mv build build-dev",
```

Then, I get mv permission denied error when I run yarn build:dev
mv error is here

```
mv: cannot move 'build' to 'build-dev/build': Permission denied  
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

I think it's because the build is not completed and mv is executed.
So, I added sleep command between react-scripts build and mv build build-dev.

```
"build:dev": "cp .env.dev ./.env && react-scripts build && sleep 5 && mv build build-dev",
```

Then, mv error hasn't occurred.
But it is not accurate the reason why mv permission denied error occurs.
So, I know accurate reason.